# How to Automate IIS Configuration and hosting with database creation/upgration?

Tags: .net, iis, automation, shared-hosting, utility

I want a utility or installer for IIS hosting. That can create a site or if already created then host my code in that site. Also it can create a database for application.
I googled but not found a way or may be I could not understand those way.
Please suggest a way so that I can do hosting in short time.
I want a automated way for hosting.

Comment: PowerShell is commonly used.

Comment: @LexLi can you provide any link for help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad as will be my answer.

1) How automate IIS site creation?

There is [IIS SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration?view=iis-dotnet) for managing IIS. You can use [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) for local and also remote operations([OpenRemote (string serverName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote?view=iis-dotnet#Microsoft_Web_Administration_ServerManager_OpenRemote_System_String_)). I'd suggest to take a look at [Using C# to Manage IIS – Microsoft.Web.Administration Namespace blog post](https://johnlnelson.com/2014/06/15/the-microsoft-web-administration-namespace/). Even it is older article, seems relevant.

2) How to host code in existing site?

I'd suggest to use same SDK to [Site.Stop()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.site.stop?view=iis-dotnet#Microsoft_Web_Administration_Site_Stop), overwrite files in site directory and then [Site.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.site.start?view=iis-dotnet#Microsoft_Web_Administration_Site_Start) again.

3) How to create a database for application? (Assuming you are talking about MS SQL)

There is [SQL Server Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-2017) with handy [programming guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-2017) and [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects/). It can be used to manipulate with server, databases and other objects via C# code. Same as you manipulate them with SQL Management Studio.

Hope it helps to achieve your goals. Cheers!

Comment: I want exactly this and I have tried this way but It has many manual things to do. I will have to create a utility to do all these line of items. I want any existing things to do this.

Comment: I have to use MySql database